# Nginx is not serving Perl files

Tags: nginx, perl, alias

I am running Nginx server on Debian 9. My problem is that, Nginx is serving Perl files in root directory, but it is not serving in alias directory (I get 403 Forbidden).

This is my configuration of alias:

```
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    server {
        listen   80;

        server_name www.example.tld example.tld;
        root /srv/!example.tld/!www;
        index  desktop.pl index.html index.htm core.tom core.pl;

        location /my_alias {

            alias /srv/!example.tld/my_alias/!www;

            location ~ /my_alias/\.pl$ {
                gzip off;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
            }
        }

        location ~ \.pl$ {
            gzip off;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
        }
    }
```

I really don't know what is wrong with it.

Everything what I want is to execute Perl files on whole server (all aliases), ideal is to execute Perl files on ALL sites (virtualhosts).

Comment: Your regexp is wrong

Comment: Please what is wrong with it?

Comment: It matches exactly one file: `.pl`. You’ve missed `.*` part of regexp

Comment: But I have this block `location ~ \.pl$ {` at root level and it works, and there is no `.*`, so what do you mean?

Comment: If you have a `location ~ \.pl$` block in the root of your configuration, you should show it in your question as it will have an effect. `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` will not work with `alias` - you should use `$request_filename`.

Comment: I updated question, I added whole configuration, everything what I want is to execute Perl files on whole server (all aliases), ideal is to execute Perl files on ALL sites (virtualhosts).